# Does @DBRef supports on aws document db?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am migrating a Spring App which has @DBRef annotations in implementation. Does this support in AWS Document DB?

Comment: I think YES. But,`@DBRef` annotation is generally not recommended for use in MongoDB.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto. im receiving an error. can you please check on this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75665029/spring-data-mongodb-dbref-resolution-is-not-supported

Comment: Contacted AWS support and they confirmed that @DBRef is not supported yet